# JSR223 PreProcessor.Passing data from the array to post request parameters

Tags: performance, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

There are 2 requests.

In the first request through the **Regular Expression Extractor** I get data that looks like

```
VAR_1=foo
VAR_2=bar
VAR_3=base
VAR_N=NNN
VAR_matchNr=N
```

The data is stored in the variable **VAR**.

In the second request I added the **JSR223 preprocessor**. I added the following code to it:

```
def array = []

1.upto(vars.get('VAR_matchNr') as int, { index ->
     array.add(vars.get('VAR_' + index))
})

vars.put('array', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(array).toPrettyString());
```

When the script runs, everything is processed correctly, the data from the **VAR** variable is converted into an array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atmHb.png)

I have the following question:

I need to pass the received data in the parameters of a POST request. Right now I'm passing through the **${array}** variable. But the entire array is transferred at once and the request is executed incorrectly. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWvR5.png)

How can I make sure that each array value in the query parameters is written as a separate parameter? At the same time, I don’t know for sure how many parameters there will be, there can be from 0 to 20 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zorZG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to amend "your" code to create [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler parameters dynamically on the fly instead of saving the matches into the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

Something like:

```
def arguments = sampler.getArguments()

1.upto(vars.get('VAR_matchNr') as int, { index ->
     arguments.addArgument(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument("list[]", vars.get('VAR_' + index)))
})

sampler.setArguments(arguments)
```

See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is working. I saw your answer to a similar question, but I couldn’t edit that code example and decided to ask a new question. Thank you!